# Android Adding extra item on listview

Tags: android, listview

I will like to add an extra item for my listview. For now i manage to list all of the categories from php but i will like to add one more "All" categories to the listview. For example:

> "All"
>  "Food"
>  "Beverage"
>  "Pastry"

How will i do that??

CategoryActivity.java

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> cateList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParserList jParser = new JSONParserList();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Categories

            catelist = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CATELIST);

            // looping through All Categories
            for(int i = 0; i < catelist.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = catelist.getJSONObject(i);

             // Storing each json item in variable

                String categories = c.getString(TAG_CATEGORIES);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_CATEGORIES, categories);

                cateList.add(map);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */           
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, cateList,
                R.layout.list_cate,
                new String[] {TAG_CATEGORIES }, new int[] {
                        R.id.categories});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

categories.php

```
    $query = 'SELECT categories FROM shop GROUP BY categories';
    $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $catelist['catelist'] = array();
    while ($output = mysql_fetch_assoc ($res)) {
    $catelist['catelist'][]=$output;
    }
    echo json_encode($catelist);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply call the following to add more new item(s):

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, cateList, R.layout.list_cate,
                new String[] {TAG_CATEGORIES }, new int[] {R.id.categories});

setListAdapter(adapter);


//to add more new items in list
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(TAG_CATEGORIES, "All");
cateList.add(map);

//refreshing the contents of list to show newly added items
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Hi, Waqas. I am adding this two line after setListAdapter(adapter).
But i am getting error message **The method add(String)/notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListAdapter** for adapter._add_ and notifyDataSetChanged();<br>
Please help me out.Thanks

Comment: I can't start the project because it is the syntax error.
Red underline on _add_ () and _notifyDataSetChanged()_

Comment: Ohh, i got it. Check my new updated answer. I've made some changes like **SimpleAdapter** and **cateList**. See if it works :)

Comment: still having Red underline on _add()_ but different message.
`The method add(HashMap<String,String>) in the type ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> is not applicable for the arguments (String)`

Comment: woops, sorry, my mistake :(  I didn't verify it on my eclipse too. Try with the new updated answer

Answer (score 0):

you can call notifyDatasetChanged() function which calles redraw on listview with updated values.

also what you can do is make your listView and listadapter member veriable and then create a function which assigns new adapter to listview

```
private SimpleAdapter adapter;
private ListView listView;

private void update()
{
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, cateList, 
                R.layout.list_cate, 
                new String[] {TAG_CATEGORIES }, new int[] { 
                        R.id.categories});
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: it is = to overriding notifyDataSetChanged function, sometimes calling notifyDataSetChanged() does not work for special conditions and overriding notifyDataSetChanged and implemting custom function is ideal.

Comment: If simple method works then why should we create new adapter again?

Comment: because sometimes it does not, and as i said try notifyDataSetChanged() and if that does not work please use provided "Sledgehammer"

Answer (score 0):

Add one extra item while parsing Json

```
map.put("ALL", All);
cateList.add(map);
```

After the above one static item is added to your list (which is always "All")

Now you can display in your list view through adapter.

Comment: What about to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`?

Comment: what about `TAG_CATEGORIES` key in map for adapter to read its corresponding value?