# Unable to refresh ListView with SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

I am trying to add a new entry to my listview and refresh it with the old entry still showing in the listview. Previously I was using ArrayAdapter which I was able to refresh after adding a new entry by using

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But I am unable to use the code above with SimpleAdapter. Any suggestion?
I have tried a couple of solutions but nothing has worked so far.

Below is the code I am using which is not adding an entry:

```
void beta3 (String X, String Y){
    //listview in the main activity
    ListView POST = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    //list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String data = bar.getText().toString();
    String two= data.replace("X", "");
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    HashMap<String,String> event = new HashMap<String, String>();
    event.put(Config.TAG_one, X);
    event.put(Config.TAG_two, two);
    event.put(Config.TAG_three, Y);
    list.add(event);
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.list,
            new String[]{Config.TAG_one, Config.TAG_two, Config.TAG_three},
            new int[]{R.id.one, R.id.two, R.id.three});        
    POST.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733572/android-adding-extra-item-on-listview).

How do you try to add the item to the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `beta3` method really is your function to add a **new** entry to your `ListView`: it will set a new adapter with a new list every time you call it. So this will always result in a `ListView` containing one entry. After exiting the `beta3` method the reference to the list is gone.

You have to reuse the `list` instance variable. Put `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list` in class/activity scope and initialize it **once** (e.g. in `onCreate()`).

Another problem is that you use a `ListAdapter` variable as reference to the `SimpleAdapter` instance. `ListAdapter` is an interface which doesn't provide a `notifyDataSetChanged` method. You should use a `SimpleAdapter` variable instead.

Here is an example:

```
public class MyActivity {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;
    SimpleAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        ListView POST = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.list,
            new String[]{Config.TAG_one, Config.TAG_two, Config.TAG_three},
            new int[]{R.id.one, R.id.two, R.id.three});        
        POST.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    void beta3 (String X, String Y){
        String two = ""; // adapt this to your needs
        ...
        HashMap<String,String> event = new HashMap<String, String>();
        event.put(Config.TAG_one, X);
        event.put(Config.TAG_two, two);
        event.put(Config.TAG_three, Y);
        list.add(event);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: my project grab the data/string from a database within the android phone and pass the data/string to beta3() and show it in the listview.
could you give me some sample code so that i can work with it?

Comment: i have tried your code. i am having error on notifyDataSetChanged() part. 
without it, the app is working but nothing is showing up on the listview.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() is showing in red. When mouse over it showing cannot resolve method 'notifyDataSetChanged()'

Comment: Replace `ListAdapter` by `SimpleAdapter`. Code example is corrected.

Comment: I have check and replace ListAdapter to SimpleAdapter but i am getting   java.lang.NullPointerException with notifyDataSetChanged() now

Comment: You have not initialized `adapter` correctly or you are calling `beta3` while `adapter` is not yet initialized. How many times appears the term `SimpleAdapter` in your code?

Comment: got it working but its refresh my listview but the older entry have been remove with the new one replacing it. i am using viewpager in my app as well.

Comment: i trigger beta3 from a button in tab2 which was use in viewpager

Comment: If the old item disappears then there's still something wrong with your code. Please compare it carefully with my sample.

Comment: You can try to simplify your code and add the button in the same view which contains your listview. Just to track down the error...

Comment: yup you are correct. there was a mix up on my part. will mark as the answer. thank you dude